# Non Clustered Indexes on data with no Logical insert order

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server database that imports data from an old VMS database.
The data has many many tables that need to be joined for reporting.

The common Id for all table Joins goes like this

```
D-100344-1 
,D-100344-2 
,D-100345-3
,D-100346-1 
,N-100346000-1 
,N-100344001-1 
,N-100344001-2 
,N-100345001-3
,N-100346000-1
```

About 1.2 million of these lines come in each day, across 827 tables.
Many times a line will come in with updated data, and I will insert and remove the earlier line as the table doesn't need duplicates.

To better facilitate joins between the tables I looked to add a non clustered index on this ID.
it became 20% fragmented after one days insert (because of course it would.

What are my options here.

fyi. I use an incrementing TableID column for a clustered index on the table so my inserts arent so terrible but that id has no relation to the other tables for joining

Comment: How is the fragmentation affecting the performance?  If it is an issue, just run a defrag job each evening.

Comment: You could shedule index maintenance after you loaded the data, to solve the fragmentation. 
Since it's for reporting, ofter indexed views can help with query performance. But you'll lose performance when inserting/updating. If your question is why is a query slow. Please share the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Is the TableID used in queries at all or does it exist only to improve insert performance? You might try a clustered index on the common_id to improve join performance. The insert/delete pattern will reuse space where needed. Specify a fill factor percent of the percentage of net new rows between reorgs. I suggest you not be overly concerned with fragmentation.

Comment: I'll be honest I dont know how its affecting performance yet as i only created the tables yesterday, we used to store everything as a heap (for like 2 years), The reporting itself is considered business critical though and i am worried that the index itself will seriously degrade performance over time.

Comment: @danguzman the tableid isnt used in queries at all, its there to insert and used to remove older lines for the same common id.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but, if tableid is used to remove older rows, then it must be used in the delete query, right? In that case, I would use a composite clustered index key of common_id and tableid.